# Example of inductive step working but not the base case

Tags: induction

Are there any examples where the inductive step works but the base case does not? I know there are some where the latter is more difficult.

Comment: Try "proving" that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2 + 1000$.

Comment: Look up the inductive 'proof' that all horses are the same color. Basically, it is 'proving' that for any set of $n\ge2$ objects: any two objects from that set are the same color. The step works, but the base fails.